# regular expression to rename pointer variables

Tags: regex, replace

I have this much

Code snippet:

```
int *filePointer;
float *valPtr;

*valPtr = 5.6;

filePointer = &sum;
```

I would like to **replace all pointer variables** as follows, for example

1. *filePointer have to be converted to *filePointer_p.
2. filePointer have to be converted to filePointer.
3. valPtr have to be converted to valPtr_p

How can I do it using **Regular Expression.**

Comment: What was that second conversion again?

Comment: Are you attempting to rename all pointer variables in a large block of code? If so, regex is an insufficient tool for that. You need a true language parser. There is no reliable way for regex to look for a `*pointer` declaration and then rename all later instances of that same pointer; furthermore, regex can't detect when a variable goes out of scope. For example, `{int *filePointer;} {float filePointer;}` is valid C or C++, but will break any sane regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you might be asking how to use regular expressions as a generic tool to rename all pointer variables in source code.  I am assuming that the provided snippet is just an example.

If my understanding of your goal is correct, it is not possible to do that with regular expressions.  A regular expression would not be able to determine reliably from the context if a variable is a pointer.  Consider, for example, `a=b;`.  `a` and `b` could be pointers or they could be most anything else.  A regular expression by itself would not be able to determine that.

Answer (score 1):

The first is simply:

```
s/\*filePointer/*filePointer_p/g
```

Not sure what you're second is on about? But if you're basically out to rename filePointer, then you should be able to simply do:

```
s/filePointer/filePointer_p/g
```

on the assumption that there aren't any other variables or context that contain the text `filePointer` in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, try `s/\*filePointer/*filePointer_p/g`.